# Преобразование int в байтовый массив. C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть int переменная, допустим 0xFF00FF00. Нужно получить байтовый массив состоящий из элементов {FF, 00, FF, 00}.

---

Вопрос. Есть ли в .NET встроенные механизмы для реализации этой задачи, если есть то какие?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Используйте BitConverter:
`BitConverter.GetBytes(Int32)`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/de8fssa4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать руками:

```
int myInt = 12345;

byte[] myByte = { 
    (byte)myInt, (byte)(myInt >> 8), (byte)(myInt >> 16), (byte)(myInt >> 24) 
};
```